# Получить значение куки

Tags: php

Есть 2 куки PHPSESSID. Одна на домене, вторая на поддомене.

На поддомене мне нужно получить значение куки которая на домене.

Пишу `$_COOKIE["PHPSESSID"]` , все работает. 
Вопрос: Всегда ли $_COOKIE выдает куку основную? Как указать явно, что нужна именна доменная кука?

Comment: Зайдите на нужную страницу и посмотрите какие куки оттуда доступны (инструменты разработчика в браузере).

Comment: я знаю, какие доступны. Доступны эти 2. Они с одинаковыми именами. Нужно получить с домена

Comment: Сделайте `var_dump($_COOKIE)` и посмотрите, что выведет

Comment: я знаю, что выводит. PHPSESSID получаю. Но всегда ли будет выдаваться доменный PHPSESSID, а не поддоменный?